# why use okhttp3 asynchronous request return "null" to another class

Tags: android, asynchronous, okhttp

The class is used to get data and using `System.out.println("First Output:"+string0);` to show whether the data be successfully invoked or not;

```
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class ToGet_Data {

    public  static String string0;


    public  static String loadData() {


        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        //构造Request,
        //builder.get()代表的是get请求，url方法里面放的参数是一个网络地址
        Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();

        final Map params = new LinkedHashMap();// 请求参数

        Request request = builder.get()
                .url("https://api.avatardata.cn/Jztk/Query?key=15f9ceafeeb94a2492fd84b8c68a554c&subject=4&model=c1&testType=rand")
                .build();
        //3将Request封装成call
        Call call = okHttpClient.newCall(request);

        //4，执行call，这个方法是异步请求数据
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                //失败调用
                Log.e("MainActivity", "onFailure: " );
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                //成功调用
                Log.e("MainActivity", "onResponse: " );

                //获取网络访问返回的字符串
                string0 = response.body().string();

                System.out.println("First Output:"+string0);

            }
        });

        return string0;
    }

}
```

this is another class to show data by using object, but `System.out.println("Second output:="+finalstring);` show null; I know it is failed.

```
package com.example.kaixuan.anull;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ToGet_Data togetdata = new ToGet_Data();
        String finalstring=togetdata.loadData();
        System.out.println("Second output:="+finalstring);
    }
}
```

[This is the result of the run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdm7m.png)

Comment: Did you notice second output was logged at first because retrofit call asynchronosly so your second output line was execute before asynchronous method finish. In this cases you values are null.

Comment: I have noticed it，But I don't know what I should do to reference the data that okhttp3 returns in other classes can you make that clear? I'm just starting to learn.thanks you!

Comment: Asynchronous means your method execute in seperate thread so your second output log line cant wait for load data to finish because above line run asynchronusly means seperate from the main thread so you probable get null. To avoid this make callback or listener to notify or update data to main activity.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer and I will follow your train of thought to find a solution，hhhhhhha！ “callback” is my Knowledge of blind area！

Comment: Welcome glad to help happy coding :)

Comment: Bother you again. I didn't find any valuable information, could you recommend some simple information to me? Or what should I change to get the return value for the above code